# displaying 'var1=var2' MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, printf

I'm having a problem displaying a message in the workspace which would basically say `'var1=var2'`, where `var1`'s are strings and contained in a vector, like this:

```
U1 = 
 u3
 v3
 u4
 v4
```

Variables' indices and the actual amount of variables may vary and determined by user's input.

`var2`'s are calculated by the function and also contained in a vector with the same size, for example:

```
U =
    0.0625
    0.2500
         0
    0.1250
```

What I want the function to display is a message like this:

```
'u3=0.0625'

'v3=0.2500'
```

and so on.

I tried this:

```
for l1=1:numel(U)
    n7=U1(l1);
    n8=U(l1);
    sprintf('''%f'', = ''%f''', n7, n8)
end
```

But that tells me that 'sprintf' is not defined for multiple inputs.

Can anyone help me with this please?? Sure it's got to be something stupid, but I just can't find an example on the web..

Comment: You should not leave the guess to the reader what type of variables you are using. Posting the output you get in the command line from displaying a variable is NOT sufficient to produce a minimal working example.

Comment: Sorry, it was late and I may have missed some points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format input should be a string:

```
sprintf('%s = %.4f', n7, n8)
```

Comment: ??? Error using ==> sprintf
Function is not defined for 'sym' inputs.

Error in ==> syscalcPS at 181
    sprintf('%s = %.4f', n7, n8)

Comment: I converted variables to strings using 'num2str' but it didn't work

Comment: Use also `n7 = char(U1(l1))` in your loop before calling the sprintf.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but a simple:

```
for a=1:length(strings)
    disp(['''', strings(a), '=', num2str(values(a)), ''''])
end
```

Should do the trick, make sure that **strings** is an array of Strings, **values** is the one containing the values, and that they have the same length.

Comment: that gives me 6 errors, the first of which says:
??? Error using ==> sym.sym>convertExpression at 2547
Error: Unexpected ''' [line 1, col 1]